# angularjs - JS string containing interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string-interpolation

Let's say my web app is getting an json response from the backend like the following:

```
[
    {id:1, description: 'this is an example 1, **value is ###**'},
    {id:2, description: 'this is an example 2, **value is ###**'},
    {id:3, description: 'this is an example 3, **value is ###**'}
]
```

There is some formatting syntax here. Text surrounded by `**` means **bold**.

This part is easy. I just need to search `**` and replace it with `<b></b>`, and then in the template I use `ng-bind-html`.

Now there is `###`. That means I have to replace it with some dynamically-changing variable. We can do this easily in the template if the entire string is hard-coded:

`<div>this is example 1, value is {{someVariable}}</div>`

How do I construct such string from Javascript?

Comment: Please share the output against the array you have shared in your question. Also, what other inputs should go into this logic?

Comment: Actually, replacing `###` is much simpler than replacing `{{someVariable}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use a custom filter something like:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('htmlReplace', function() {
    // `input` is the description string, otherVar is `someVariable` in view
    return function(input, otherVar) {
       let html = input.replace(...// do your replacing           
       return html;
    }
  })
```

View

```
<div ng-bind-html="obj.description | htmlReplace: someVariable"></div>
```